# How to aggregate data in rows into several and perform other SQL operation with them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, sqlcommand

I have a table (result of selecting from some table, ordered by the Change column) like this:

```
ID      Change
1001    4
1002    4
1003    4
1004    3
1005    3
1006    2
...     ...
```

And I want to update another table with above data as below:

```
update sometable set columnA=columnA + 4 where ID in (1001, 1002, 1003)
update sometable set columnA=columnA + 3 where ID in (1004, 1005)
update sometable set columnA=columnA + 2 where ID in (1006)
...
```

How could I perform this with SQL command?

Answer (score 0):

try this in Test sample data,

```
declare @t table(ID int,Change int)
insert into @t values (1001,4),(1002,4),(1003,4),(1004,3),(1005,3),(1006,2)

update s set s.columnA=s.columnA + t.change 
from sometable S
inner join @t t on s.id=t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case the below is schema..

```
    CREATE TABLE #TAB(ID INT,      Change INT)
    INSERT INTO #TAB
    SELECT 1001 ,   4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,    4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003  ,  4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1004,    3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1005 ,   3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1006,    2
```

Now we can  handle it using For XML Path and Stuff and a CTE as below

```
    ;WITH CTE AS(
     SELECT DISTINCT CHANGE
    ,STUFF( (SELECT ', '+CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(100))  FROM #TAB T2 
     WHERE T2.Change= T.CHANGE  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') ID_PK FROM #TAB T
    )
    SELECT 'UPDATE SOMETABLE SET COLUMN_A= COLUMN_A+ '+CAST(CHANGE AS VARCHAR(10))+' WHERE ID IN ('+ID_PK +') ;'  FROM  CTE
```